# c++ Vector out of range with shifting variable

Tags: c++, vector, outofrangeexception

So I have an assignment where I have a stoplight that shifts directions and allows cars to pass through one by one. The directions changes in clockwise order. I implemented a code that reads the initial starting direction, cars passing per direction and one that reads the license plate, direction and how long it takes to pass. The problems occur when it shifts from E to S to W to N, but then it gets stuck and I encounter vector out of range

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

struct cars
{
    string name;
    char dr;
    int t;
};

bool init(vector<cars> &arr, char direct)
{
    for (auto i = 0; arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if (arr.at(i).dr == direct)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}

char direct_shift(char e)
{
    if (e == 'N')
    {
        return 'E';
    }
    else if (e == 'E')
    {
        return 'S';
    }
    else if (e == 'S')
    {
        return 'W';
    }
    else if (e == 'W')
    {
        return 'N';
    }
    else
    {
        return '\0';
    }
}


int main() {

    vector <cars> keeper;
    queue <cars> que;

    char track;  //starting direction
    int car_num;    //starting car num

    string n;
    char d;
    int sec;
    cin >> track;
    cin >> car_num;

    while (cin >> n >> d >> sec) //takes the input if plate, direction and time
    {
        cars temp;
        temp.name = n;
        temp.dr = d;
        temp.t = sec;
        keeper.push_back(temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < keeper.size(); i++) {
        cout << keeper[i].name << " " << keeper[i].dr << " " << keeper[i].t << endl;
    }  //checks if it all inputted it
    char curr_dir = track;

    while (not keeper.empty())
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < keeper.size(); i++) {
        reset:
            if (init(keeper, curr_dir) == true)
            {
                if (keeper[i].dr == curr_dir) {
                    que.push(keeper.at(i)); //pushes vector at i into queue
                    keeper.erase(keeper.begin() + i); // deletes vector at index i
                    cout << que.front().name << " Going to " << que.front().dr << " at " << que.front().t << endl;
                    que.pop();
                    curr_dir = direct_shift(curr_dir);
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                curr_dir = direct_shift(curr_dir);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `for` loop condition `arr.size()` looks like a mistake. You probably meant `i < arr.size()`. Otherwise it will loop forever (or until if `break`s) for a non-empty `arr`. Edit : Since you use `.at` it looks like it might also end when an exception is throw. Edit 2 : Which I guess is the out of range exception you are asking about.

Comment: It still works with that for loop.

Comment: The specific error im getting is this
1>ABC N 2
1>BCD N 2
1>CDE S 3
1>DEF E 2
1>EFG S 1
1>FGH W 1
1>DEF Going to E at 2
1>CDE Going to S at 3
1>FGH Going to W at 1
1>ABC Going to N at 2
1>terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
1>  what():  vector::_M_range_check

Comment: you are erasing from the vector while iterating it, thats a bit tricky. You have to take into account that after erasing element at `i` the next element is at index `i` not `i+1`

Comment: would using a while loop be a better one for this?

Comment: i tried while loop, however i encounter more errors where it stops beforehand at before going through a whole clockwise loop

Comment: the out of range is most likely from what FrançoisAndrieux mentioned. `arr.size()` causes that loop to never stop, `while` wont help, you need to fix the stop condition, there might be other errors though

Comment: With all due respect, Jeremy, your statement "It still works with that for loop" is incredibly assumptive. If it did, frankly, you wouldn't be here. The only cases where that loop in that `init` function "works" is when the vector is *empty*, or at least one element has a `dr` member that is equivalent to `direct`. If neither of those are true, that loop is a recipe for infinite spin. There is nothing in the body of the loop except the equivalence check + return that potentially alters the outcome of the conditional statement of the for loop. That in itself should be serious food for thought.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're having problems due to the following function:

```
bool init(vector<cars> &arr, char direct) {

  for (auto i = 0; arr.size(); i++) {
       if (arr.at(i).dr == direct) { 
            return true; 
        } 
   } return false; 

}
```

`arr.at(i)` will throw `out_of_range` exception if you try to access a non-existent index. Which means you need to guarantee that your vector is not empty/within size before you access index.

```
bool init(vector<cars> &arr, char direct) { 
     //the loop now checks for (!arr.empty()) 
         for (vector<cars>::size_type i = 0; i <arr.size(); ++i) { 
             if (arr.at(i).dr == direct) {
                  return true; } 
          } return false; 

}
```

Comment: you fixed the code but your explanation if off, once the loop condition is fixed the loop also works  for an empty vector no need to check for an empty vector explicitly